# php pdt for eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

i've installed pdt for eclipse
i've built a new project, added a new php file, but my intellisence only works for my varriable abe methods..
how can i make it work for php core functions? like "socket_listen" etc.. ?

i'm using it for android development and it works great, and i would really be glad if it could help me autocomplete my code.

inside my project i have the php language library with all the functions and php files needed but from some reason eclipse doesn't use it.

any suggestions ?